# php file downloading instead of showing up on browser?

Tags: php, filezilla

I'm running this from Filezilla remote server
anyone have any solution

```
<?php

echo "what a lab";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a web browser to load the output of a PHP file you need to make an HTTP request to an HTTP server which supports PHP.

FileZilla is an FTP client. It connects to FTP servers. FireZilla, if it comes into it at all, will be used only to copy the PHP file **to** the computer which is running both an FTP and HTTP server.

You need to enter the matching HTTP URL (e.g. `http://example.com/your.php`) into the address bar of your browser.

Comment: im using the knuth server with it

Comment: What is the knuth server? I've never heard of it and Google just finds Donald Knuth's homepage.

Comment: its knuth.griffith.ie

Comment: OK, so that is Donald Knuth's homepage. I've no idea if it supports PHP or not or why you think it does. Maybe you should talk to your system administrator.